# Is there a way to display HTML code in Nginx instead of executing it?

Tags: html, nginx

I want to display HTML code instead of executing it in Nginx, is that possible?

Comment: HTML isn't a subject to execute, what do you mean by "execute it"? You can return some arbitrary HTML string via `return 200 "<some HTML here>";` directive.

Comment: Do you mean in a browser? Set the content type to `text/plain`.